# Abstractions and Architecture for populating relational databases

Tags: mysql, sql, database, orm, relational-database

So I've been writing 20 page sql statements to insert form data into my database system and even looked at ORM's which require that I have a db with an IQ below 60 (no UUID triggers, no composite keys, no bidirectional tables, no many to many to one hybrid tables, etc etc) and basically just one denormalized mess just to get the ORM to play nice. I've looked into stored procedures and what have you.

But so far, I just cant take the pain off of populating a relational database that has 10+ tables, 50+ tables, and sometimes even 70+ tables. Is there a secret solution I don't know about? And if not, does the pain eventually turn numb? Will I ever stop crying?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest that the more complex the forms you have, the more pain you'll experience in storing it. No getting around that. More inputs = more validation, more SQL, more everything.

But some ideas that might make life a bit easier:

1. Don't give up on ORMs just yet. There are a ton of them around and you might consider switching languages to find one that works well for you.
2. You might consider moving to a totally denormalized database with something like Mongo. It makes writing and reading data a lot easier since you don't have to constantly normalize your form data. You just serialize an object and write it.
3. Stored procedures can assume a lot of the code you would otherwise write in the application layer. If you write a few sprocs to read/write objects, then the good news is you only need to write them once and you can re-use them over and over. Only useful if you're duplicating some of the CRUD SQL in your application layer now.